# Mootools new Element does not work

Tags: javascript, mootools

new Element does not work. Someone has any clue why?
css:

```
#tileNode {
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

js:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
var newElement = new Element('div',{id:"tileNode"});
newElement.inject($$('div#tileNode'));
alert($$('#tileNode').get('id'));
});
```

Alerting #root works fine so it exists... creating that tileNode element does not work alerting it also does not work :/

Kind regards!

Comment: `newElement.inject($('root'));` if you inject in the div with the id 'root',also you have to inject in a single element, use $('id') because the $$ returns an array…

Comment: i've put it as an answer, you can mark it answered for the next one ! ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can also use this to inject:

```
newElement.inject($$('div#tileNode')[0]);
```

Comment: creating an array of elements when you look for a unique element does not make sense ! `$('tileNode')` is more accurate, simpler to understand and more optimised !

Answer (score 1):

use

```
newElement.inject($('root'));
```

If you inject in the div with the id 'root',also you have to inject in a single element, use $('id') because the $$ returns an array…

Answer (score 1):

There are few things in your code that took my attention:
Fist is, `new Element('div',{id:"tileNode"})` is completely equal to `new Element('div[id=tileNode]')`. Since it makes no difference what way you choose, I'd recommend  the second form, because it is a lot more readable. You could even add more attributes like `Element('div[id=tileNode][class=tile]')` and so on, instead of passing an object.

Another optimization would be to use the [dollar function](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollar) if you are trying to get an element by its id. So if you want to alert the id of an element, try to use `alert($('tileNode').id)`.
Though alerting might work fine, you could try to use the javascript console. Instead of `alert(myVar)` use `console.log(myVar)`.

Hope this helps, and happy coding :)